# Wifi light switch

Tags: wiring, neutral, smart-switch

I want to install a wifi light switch. It has a line, load, neutral and ground posts. Original switch is 14/2 with White, black, ground. Can this wifi switch be wired into this configuration? Thanks.

Comment: If there is 1 *cable* in the box with 3 *wires* (white, black, bare/green), then you have a **switch loop**.  The white wire should be *always-hot* (required, to make it easier for novices to realize the white is not neutral in this case). The black is *switched-hot*.  Neutral is not present.  The latest code also requires the white wire be marked with black tape or paint to indicate "not neutral".

Answer (score 4):

Many wifi switches get power for their internal electronics from the supply wire and the neutral.  Without a neutral, they can't get power and won't work.  So, the bad news is that if there is no neutral wire in the switch box, you can't use that particular switch.

The good news is that they do make smart switches that don't require a neutral - you just have to know to look for them.

To understand your wiring better, you can look up "switch loop".

Comment: There is a neutral in the box. I tried the black to line and got a pulsating light. Tried to load and got nothing.  Would I be able to connect a second black wire to the single hot then run the hot to load and the second hot to line?

Comment: So what wires were hooked up to the old switch, and what additional wires do you have in the box?  Just because there is a white wire there doesn't mean its a neutral. @FrankVanVeen

Comment: @FrankVanVeen if the only wires you have in that box are 1 black, 1 white & 1 ground - then no you do not have neutral. White is not neutral in a switch loop.